# select ... from select - subquery with Core-Data

Tags: ios, sql, core-data

Is is possible to perform a `SELECT ... FROM SELECT` query with Core-Data ?
I'm working on just one entity.

Of course I can work with the Dictionary result but I would prefer to make a complicated query which returns a ready-to-go result

EDIT : 
Here is the query I want to perform

```
SELECT zcp, sum(zce), sum(zce)*100/zcpva, sum(zce)/
   (SELECT sum(zis) 
    FROM (
       SELECT zis 
       FROM zbma 
       GROUP BY zim, zis)
    ) 
FROM zbma 
GROUP BY  zcp, zcpva;
```

Comment: It would help if you describe the Core Data entities and relationships and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have just one entity without relationships, I would like to compute a price for each items, so I need to compute a global sum, then for each item, divide the price with this sum

Comment: here is the working query I want to perform select zcp, sum(zce), sum(zce)*100/zcpva, sum(zce)/(select sum(zis) from (select zis from zbma group by zim, zis)) from zbma group by  zcp, zcpva;

Comment: @Max You might want to put that last comment (about your "working query") into your question.